# Limit sql query and rank according to total

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query for my MYSQL DB and want to limit the results to only 10 sales people instead of 20. I have tried inserting their names inside the query but keep getting error. Also is it possible to rank according to total. The sql query I am using is:

```
select sales_id, totalbuy, totalsell, totalbuy + totalsell as total from
(select sales_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell
from sales_id where sales_id='sales1', GROUP BY sales_id)q
```

where it says sales1 I have attempted to add the remaining 9 sales_ids' using a comma and single quotes but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want certain sales_id only, use the "IN " clause.

if you wanna only the top 10 total, remove that line and use LIMIT

```
select sales_id, totalbuy, totalsell, totalbuy + totalsell as total from
(select owner_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell
from sales_id  
where sales_id in ('sales1', 'sales2', 'sales3', 'sales4')-- if you wanna certain sales_id only
GROUP BY sales_id)q
order by total desc
limit 0, 10;--top 10 by total (bigger first)
```

Comment: I got this error check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY sales_id)q
order by total desc
limit 0, 10' at line 4